# How to find out if my debian server setup is a dual core or not?

Tags: debian, central-processing-unit

I have access to root and would like to find out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
```

That should give info about how many cores are available and which type they are.

Comment: `cat /proc/cpuinfo|grep processor|wc -l` if all you want is a number ;)

Comment: @Amazed http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_(Unix)#Useless_use_of_cat

Comment: @sciurus you use your felines as you will, and I shall do the same :P

Answer (score 5):

The place to look is /proc/cpuinfo, as others have said. However, at a glance this does not tell you whether a server is dual-core. If you see two entries, it could be because

- the server has one processor with two cores
- the server has one processor that supports hyperthreading
- the server has two processors with one core each

For example, take this information from cpuinfo.

```
$ grep processor /proc/cpuinfo
processor   : 0
processor   : 1
processor   : 2
processor   : 3
processor   : 4
processor   : 5
processor   : 6
processor   : 7
```

I can see that there are 8 logical processors, but I don't know how many CPUs and cores there are.

```
$ grep 'physical id' /proc/cpuinfo
physical id : 0
physical id : 0
physical id : 0
physical id : 0
physical id : 0
physical id : 0
physical id : 0
physical id : 0
```

Now I know there is only one CPU, but I don't know if it has 8 cores or 4 cores and hyperthreading.

```
$ grep 'core id' /proc/cpuinfo
core id     : 0
core id     : 1
core id     : 2
core id     : 3
core id     : 0
core id     : 1
core id     : 2
core id     : 3
```

Now I have the complete picture; this is a single quad-core CPU with hyperthreading.